# SharePoint Designer Workflow LookUp in emails don't return data

Tags: workflow, email

I have a strange situation...  From SharePoint Designer, for a List, I create a workflow, for SharePoint 2013 platform.  As my first action, I ask SPD to send an email to the user that created the item.  This works fine.

As the email title, I used:  New Ticket `[%Current Item: ID%]`.  This works fine, the email title is converted as it should "New Ticket 23".

My problem is in the email body, I use the "Add/Edit Lookup" and select Current Item > Title.

When I receive the email, the body contains `[%Current Item:Title%]` instead of the Item's title.

Is someone knows how to correct this ?  Is there something I have to activate somewhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem !  Now, I have to find a way to bring it to Microsoft.  Here is the explanation, maybe it will help someone out there.

I am using SPD to create the workflow.  When I click on the *email action* link, it opens the Email definition window, with a WYSIWYG tool to create the email to be sent.

The problem is right there.  The WYSIWYG tool.
Clicking OK will convert the text to HTML.  It converts lookups too.  If I insert `[%Variable : strText%]`, the WYSIWYG tool converts it to `[%Variable&nbsp;: strText%]`, which is not recognized by SharePoint.

To bypass the *problem*, I use the WYSIWYG tool to create a template (font, size, color...), and then, right-click on the Workflow action, select "Properties", and then, access the Body HTML code to add lookup fields.  This way, the `[%Variable : strText%]` isn't converted to HTML code, and the value is perfectly inserted in the email.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `[%Current Item:Title%]`, Choose `[%Current Item:Name%]` in Add or Change Lookup.

Comment: Thank you, but I get the exact same thing:
Email title = New ticket 7
Email body = [%Current Item:Name%]